# Plotting Pandas GroupBy data

Tags: python, pandas

I read a dataset into `Pandas` and filtered the data using `df_new=df.query("parent=='pr1'")` to create a new `DataFrame` which looks like this:

```
     child  parent         date     pres  
101   ch05     pr1   2004-06-01  2760.35  
102   ch05     pr1   2004-07-08  2758.83  
103   ch09     pr1   2004-08-04  2759.13  
..     ...     ...          ...           
317   ch12     pr1   2021-03-15  1737.09  
318   ch12     pr1   2021-03-17  1730.98  
183   ch05     pr1   2021-04-30  1777.09
```

I am trying to calculate the daily average so tried this: `pobs = df.groupby('date')['pres'].mean()`.  This seems to work because `print(pobs)` gives something like this:

```
date
2004-06-01    2760.35
2004-07-08    2758.83
2004-08-04    2759.13
```

However I want to plot `date` against `pres` using `matplotlib` to make sure but have not been able to extract the two arrays separately.  I tried tweaking the solution here [Plotting pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825736/plotting-pandas-groupby) but have got myself tied up in knots.  I suspect the answer is one or two lines of code but I just can't find them - all suggestions appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reset the index

```
pobs = df.groupby('date')['pres'].mean().reset_index()
```

output:

```
    date    pres
0   2004-06-01  2760.35
1   2004-07-08  2758.83
2   2004-08-04  2759.13
```

In this way, prob is now a dataframe and can be plotted as such, for example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(pobs.date,pobs.pres)
```